# extract part of URL from parent URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

For this url

```
"http://testsite/sites/TestSubSite/objstrat/CultureConnection/Pages/default.aspx"
```

Trying to extract everything after enterprise/sites.
I want `"/TestSubSite/objstrat/CultureConnection/Pages/default.aspx"`

I can get the filename like this:

```
var filename = parenturl.substring(parenturl.lastIndexOf("/") + );
```

But not sure how to extract from the middle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lastIndexOf` will fail for any URI reference with `/` in the fragment or query, as in `http://example.com/foo/bar#/baz/boo`.

---

Libraries like [Google Closure's Uri module](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_Uri.html) can make this easy.

```
new goog.Uri(parenturl).getPath()
```

---

If your library of choice doesn't have URI support, then http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt appendix B suggests

```
var urlRegex = /^(([^:\/?#]+):)?(\/\/([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?/;
var path = decodeURIComponent(urlRegex.exec(parenturl)[5]);
```

will get you the path part.

---

Once you've got the path, you can then strip off the `/sites/` part by doing something like

```
var pathSuffix = path.replace(/^\/sites\//, '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

I love Javascript with DOM element.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "http://testsite/sites/TestSubSite/objstrat/CultureConnection/Pages/default.aspx";

link.protocol;
link.hostname;
link.port;
link.pathname;
link.search;
link.hash;
link.host;

link.pathname.replace(/^\/sites/,"") // "/TestSubSite/objstrat/CultureConnection/Pages/default.aspx"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing might be to use javascript's Split() function and rebuild the string from the resulting array (leaving out the first couple items)

```
    var parenturl = "http://testsite/sites/TestSubSite/objstrat/CultureConnection/Pages/default.aspx";
        var tokens = parenturl.split("/");

    for(var i=0;i<tokens .length;i++)
    {
        console.log(tokens [i]);
    }
```

Comment: This fails if there is a `/` in the fragment or query.

Answer (score 0):

Hows about:

```
var parenturl = "http://testsite/sites/TestSubSite/objstrat/CultureConnection/Pages/default.aspx";
var filename = parenturl.match(/\/sites(.*)$/)[1];
alert(filename);
```

Comment: This fails if there is a `/sites` in the fragment or query or the domain name starts with `sites` as in `http://sitestest/`

Comment: it does *not* fail if there is a `/sites` in the fragment or query, as his problem suggests that the `/sites` appears as the first part of the fragment, therefore `var parenturl = "http://testsite/sites/TestSubSite/sites/CultureConnection/Pages/default.aspx";` would return `/TestSubSite/sites/CultureConnection/Pages/default.aspx` as expected. It will fail if there is `/sites` in the domain, but I presume he knows what the domain is and that it will be the same in all cases.

Comment: Agree via fragment/query.  In my experience, apps often get deployed on different sites as they are l10ned, partner, and just maintained which makes site assumptions brittle, and if you test on a different domain than the ones you deploy on, hard to debug too.